# ActiveMQ SSL activation

Tags: ssl, activemq-classic

I have an MQTT broker with ActiveMQ on an Ubuntu server with Windows clients. Now I want to enable SSL. I found [the tutorial](https://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl.html), but I have a question.

This step 1: I do on Mqtt broker activemq

*Step 1 Create a certificate for the broker with keytool:*

```
keytool -genkey -alias broker -keyalg RSA -keystore broker.ks
```

*Step 2 export the broker's certificate so it can be shared with clients: This action on MQTT broker Server. Certificat will be installed on Windows cleint.*

```
keytool -export -alias broker -keystore broker.ks -file broker_cert
```

*Step 3 see below Create a certificate/keystore for the client:
Do I need this step? where to perform this step? On client or Mqtt broker server? but there are windows cleint.*

```
keytool -genkey -alias client -keyalg RSA -keystore client.ks
```

*Step 4. Do I need this step? where to perform this step? On client or MQTT broker server? but there are windows client.

Create a truststore for the client, and import the broker's certificate. This will ensure that the client "trusts" the broker:*

```
keytool -import -alias broker -keystore client.ts -file broker_cert
```

What do I have to do now to make the broker and the windows client use the certificate?

Comment: Are "MQTT broker" and "ActiveMQ" two different things or the same thing?

Comment: Also, do you really want to use self-signed certificates or do you plan on getting your certificates signed but a trusted authority?

Comment: You need to narrow down your question. On Stack Overflow a question should focus only on a *single* problem. When you ask multiple questions it makes it difficult to identify a correct answer. For example, what if an answer only addresses one part of your question? Assuming that it's accurate, is it "correct"? What if there are 2 answers and they each accurately address different parts of your question. Which one is "correct"? This kind of ambiguity is bad for community involvement and devalues the content. Please ask questions that focus on a single issue. Thanks!

Comment: Hello Bertram, Thanks for the answer. "MQTT broker" and "ActiveMQ" two different things or the same thing? This is the same Thing.  Yes i want to use self-signed certificates. Thanks and regard.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions cover both the broker-side and client-side.

The broker hosts the self-signed SSL certificate to hand out on SSL connections, and the client needs the key in a 'truststore' to allow the key from the broker since it is self-signed and not from one of the public SSL key signers that are already provided by most OS and dev stacks.

Keep in mind-- SSL encrypts the traffic, but also maintains 'who to trust'. Just b/c some server hands out a SSL key, doesn't mean the client should simply encrypt and start passing data to that server.

EDIT: Some config samples

At minimum:

```
<broker ..
  .. 
  <sslContext>
    <sslContext keyStore="broker1-keystore.ks"
                keyStorePassword="password"/>
  </sslContext>
  ..
</broker>
```

Advanced ref: https://activemq.apache.org/ssl-transport-reference

Comment: @Pavlovich that means: first Create a certificate for the broker with keytool: and export the certificate (broker_cert) and install it on windows cleint. Is that right ?  Another question, still i need to make some changes in activemq.xml configuration so that the broker uses the certificat and listen on SSL. ?

Comment: @sondavid2020 yes, you add a sslContext at a minimum. There are advanced configs to do other scenarios, but the general sample -- clients connect and trust the broker -- is posted above

Answer (score 0):

@Pavlovich
I installed the certificate on client.
I change `activeqm.xml` like:

```
transportConnector name="ssl" uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:61714?transport.enabledProtocols=TLSv1.2"/>
```

I'm trying to test the connection with a certificate using mqtt fx and it doesn't work.
i keep getting mqtt exception

```
ERROR --- BrokerConnectService           : MqttException
```

Thx